# Permissions issue with Centos

Tags: centos, permissions

I've got a problem with folder permissions on CentOS.

I have a folder called `website`, which was created by the root user via ssh, with setting 775 permissions. Now, I have a second account, called `wiki`, which is in one of the secondary groups of the root user.

Sending `groups root` and `groups wiki` commands gives these results:

root:

```
$ groups root
root : root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel psacln
```

wiki:

```
$ groups wiki
wiki : psacln
```

The common group is `psacln`, so why, with wiki user, can't I create any folder in the `website` folder?

Comment: What have you already tried to resolve the problem?  What research have you done?  What was the result of that research?

Comment: The folder should be owned by the group "psacln".

Comment: What's the group for this folder ? You aren't using ACLs do you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wiki` user doesn't have any rights in that directory, because the group on the directory's permissions is going to be `root`'s primary group, `root`, not one of its other groups.

You should `chown` the directory to the `wiki` user, or to one of its groups (probably not the `psacln` since that group is for an unrelated application).

Answer (score -1):

The user psacln is part of the both the root and wiki groups, meaning that psacln(user) gains the group permissions of any file owned by the root or wiki group.  However the website directory being owned by root.root doesn't give group permissions to the wiki user because wiki isn't part of the root group.  I would chown the file to wiki being that root already has permission to read and write to everything.

Comment: Man groups : *groups - print the groups a user is in*.